# item losing value after assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object, and I'm adding a function to it at run-time with a value that's generated at run-time as well (sort of)

```
//in my service
var model = {
 id: 0,
 name: 'one',
 refs: {
  list: [{id: 0, name: 'ref1'}, .... ]
 }
}

//in controller
model.useRefs = function() { logRefs(model.refs.list); };

//in service
function logRefs(objectList) {
 //getting an empty list here for objectList 
 var length = objectList.length;
 for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  console.log(objectList[i].name);
 }
}
```

for some reason, the objectList parameter is just an empty array when the function `logRefs` is invoked (by calling `model.useRefs()`) but the array has values when the function is assigned to `useRefs`

the weird thing is, I have this same exact code for another part of my app, and its working fine.

---

I guess I should add that I'm using angular, and some of this code is in the controller while other parts are in a service.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/s7qptz2s/1/

sadly... its working in the fiddle, but not in my environment...

Comment: are you sure, that when you call `object.useRefs` _object.refs.list_ already fill? can you provide working sample?

Comment: @Grundy yea, positive. I'm initializing it with some values to begin with. and when debugging, `object.useRefs = function() {....}` it has a value on that line

Comment: Checked in console. Code works fine.

Comment: object is a reserved word, if you are using "object" as your object's name, it will misbehave.

Comment: @Banana i'm not actually using the word object

Comment: @AbdulAhmad then please adjust your code snippet to reflect your exact erroneous code

Comment: @Banana my bad, taken care of

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, can you provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in snippet inside question, or jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: @Grundy I'll attempt, give me a few minutes

Comment: @Grundy fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/s7qptz2s/1/

Comment: @Grundy its working in the fiddle, but not in my environment...

Comment: do you fill this array with ajax for example? or it hardcoded?

Comment: @Grundy its hard coded on start of the app (then items are added later as well)

Comment: @Grundy see my answer below for a fix that worked if interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - I don't know why but changing the code around worked. EVEN THOUGH the code I have up at the top is working in fiddle, and not working in my environment, the following worked for me:

I changed this:

```
model.useRefs = function() { logRefs(model.refs.list); };
```

to this:

```
model.useRefs = assignUseRefs(model.refs.list);

function assignUseRefs(refs) {
  return function() {
    return logRefs(refs);
  }
}
```

why angular, why... (or should I blame javascript)

Comment: if this works, then before you call your function `useRefs` you change reference to `model.refs.list` that's why you can think that it filled. But i need see full code to say what indeed wrong with your code

Comment: @Grundy yea you're right, the reference is changing that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Define your `model` object and `logRefs` function as "united" service:
*(I'll use some exemplary names for application, service and controller - replace them with your current names)*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// defining service
myApp.factory('myService', function() {
    return {
        model : {
              id: 0,
              name: 'one',
              refs: {
                 list: [{id: 0, name: 'ref1'}, .... ]
              }
        },
        logRefs: function(objectList) {
                    //getting an empty list here for objectList 
                    var length = objectList.length;
                    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                       console.log(objectList[i].name);
                    }
        }
    };
});

// controller
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    myService.model.useRefs = function() {
        myService.logRefs(myService.model.refs.list); 
    };
}]);
```